# nginx subfolders redirections

Tags: html, .htaccess, nginx, redirect

I want to make redirections in my nginx for my pelican blog. Here is my initial adress (or it will look like…):

/year/month/day/article/

So for ex :
/2014/01/07/some-article/

what I want is that, if nginx don't find any of the last subfolder, it serves the parent (and continuing to the root).

So in the url /2014/01/07/some-article/ if it doesn't find the folder "some-article" it serves the parent folder "07". But again, if it doesn't find it, serve the "01", then continue the logic to year, and finally root.

BTW, if you read stupid config, please advice me. I took the config from my currently running website, so it may not be accurate for the pelican blog.

here is what looks like the config file now (not yet tested) :

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name my.server.com;
root /pelican/;

index index.html;

location / {
    rewrite ^/fr/feed/ /fr/feed/rss.xml permanent;
    rewrite ^/en/feed/ /en/feed/rss.xml permanent;
    rewrite ^/en/ / permanent;
    rewrite ^/fr/ / permanent;

            try_files $url;
    }

# This block will catch static file requests, such as images, css, js
# The : prefix is a "non-capturing" mark, meaning we do not require
# the pattern to be captured into $1 which should help improve performance
location ~* \.(:ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|png)$ {
# Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
expires max;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

# remove the robots line if you want to use wordpress" virtual robots.txt
location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
```

}

Comment: You are using 301 redirect. so take a look at it https://jeffsebring.com/2012/nginx-301-redirects/ 1st your root path is wrong. its should full path like `root /home/public_html/pelican/;`  for feed its look like this  `rewrite ^/fr/feed/ /fr/feed/rss.xml last;
rewrite ^/en/feed/ /en/feed/rss.xml last;` Is is WordPress?

Comment: change `try_files $url;` with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;`

Comment: the aim is to make an almost transparent migration to pelican… so it WAS wordpress :D

but your last suggestion is obviously wrong.
And the root (/home/public…) is wrong also. I don't see why you say that. It should be (depending on the case) /home/username/public_html/pelican.

In my case, it will be /var/www/pelican… No matter.

Comment: I said it because /pelican/ is wrong. Its wrong path. It was not full path. Its was like /etc/ directory. If was /pelican/ nginx will give 404 error. because that Directory does not exists.

Comment: you can make it exist... it's no bideal if you want/need.

But at present, it doesn't solve my problem (redirect to the parent folder if the current asked doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the thing.

Here is my new config :

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name xxxxxxxxx;
root /var/www/pelican/;

index index.html rss.xml;

# faillite du nom de l'article
location ~* ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3/;
    }

# faillite du jour
location ~* ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/;
    }

# faillite du mois
location ~* ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/;
    }

# faillite de l'annee et des langues
location ~* ^/([0-9]+)/$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
    }

}
```